# ALM 12 REST using SpringFramework RestTemplate: "401 QCSession cookie missing"

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate, alm

In ALM 12 we have to explicity call "qcbin/rest/site-session" to get session.
When I GET call "/qcbin/rest/site-session" I receive the following:

```
"Set-Cookie=[BIGipServerALMAST330P-QC=rd100o00000000000000000000ffff0fe0dd74o8080; path=/, ]""
```

I extract the cookie as described here:
[HP ALM 12 REST not returning QCSession cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209167/hp-alm-12-rest-not-returning-qcsession-cookie). 
Instead of this RestConnector, our project is using RestTemplate from SpringFramework, so I did:

```
        private HashMap getQCSession() throws Exception {
            URL url = new URL("https://almxxxx.saas.hp.com/qcbin/rest/site-session?login-form-required=y");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
            conn.connect();

            HashMap cookies = updateCookies(conn);
            return cookies;
        }


        public HashMap updateCookies(HttpURLConnection conn) {
            String cookie2 = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");             
            int equalIndex = cookie2.indexOf('=');
            int semicolonIndex = cookie2.indexOf(';');
            String cookieKey = cookie2.substring(0, equalIndex);
            String cookieValue = cookie2.substring(equalIndex + 1, semicolonIndex);

            HashMap cookies = new HashMap();
            cookies.put(cookieKey, cookieValue);
            System.out.println(cookies.toString());
            return cookies;
        }
```

To send the cookie in the GET call using the RestTemplate I followed the instructions from http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/08/sending-cookies-with-resttemplate/, so I did:

```
public <U extends Object> ResponseEntity<U> getFromURL(URI url, Class<U> responseBodyClass) throws Exception {
        logger.info("GET na URL: {} esperando classe: {} no response", url, responseBodyClass);

        HashMap cookie = this.getQCSession();
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add("Cookie", this.getQCSession().toString());
        this.httpEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);

        return super.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, this.httpEntity, responseBodyClass);
    }
```

The requestHeaders content added to the HttpEntity (SpringFramework) is:

```
{Cookie=[{BIGipServerALMAST330P-QC=rd100o00000000000000000000ffff0fe0dd74o8080}]}
```

However I'm still getting "401 QCSession cookie missing".

I already tried to send in the GET call the JSESSIONID, with no success as well.

I appreciate any help. 
Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this.  As of ALM12 you need to create a session also.

I POST some XML or JSON to here "/authentication-point/alm-authenticate" to authenticate
Then collect the Set-Cookie header
I then POST to "/rest/site-session" with the cookie from the previous response.
I collect the session cookies from that response to use in my subsequent requests.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm using the example RestConnector, but POST to "/rest/site-session" is returning only 
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length. I tried send some data but thats Bad Request return...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if it can help you but you are sending it with query param for UI authentication.

```
"POST .../rest/site-session?login-form-required=y"
```

I would suggest to POST it without query param

```
"POST .../rest/site-session"
```

Also the order of actions you should do before asking for QCSession token is:

1.Check whether you are authenticated

```
 "GET .../rest/is-authenticated"
```

2.If not you'll get reference where to authenticate: **WWW-Authenticate: LWSSO realm=".../authentication-point"**

3.Send basic auth header to authentication point with added **alm-authenticate** at the end. Which returns you LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY.

```
"POST .../authentication-point/alm-authenticate"
Authentication: Basic BASE64{username:password}
```

4.Then you'll need to POST that LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY to site-session and ALM will return you QCSession key.

```
"POST .../rest/site-session"
"Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY={cookie}; Path=/"
```

Hopefully I was able to help you. 
If you still have problems, feel free to contact me.